# how to initialize dynamic object array

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor, new-operator

what if i create array of objects dynamically , then how to initialize instance data members . Because at the time of using new keyword only array dimension can be mentioned not the arguments for constructor.

Comment: Use `std::vector` and spare your sanity.

Answer (score 0):

> Because at the time of using new keyword only array dimension can be mentioned not the arguments for constructor.

The canonical way in the c++ language is to use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector):

```
std::vector<int> array(10, 42);
                //     ^   ^
                //     |   | the value
                //     |  the size
```

Another way to initialize the `std::vector` with different values is to use a [`std::initializer_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) like so:

```
std::vector<int> array = { 1, 2 , 3, 4, 5, 6 , 55, 0, -2, 42, -16 };
```

---

#### Note:

In c++ you should use `new` and `delete` only for ***very rare*** cases in your own code. These are really advanced and you have to be 100% sure that your use case really demands to do that.

Manual memory management is usually not necessary at all, and the c++ standard library provides

- a very broad collection of [Container classes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container)
- a number of [Smart pointer classes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory)

which relieve you from all of the pitfalls of manual dynamic memory management.
Just use that stuff, anyone who demands you to do something else is most probably incompetent, or was fooled by myths telling that using the stuff from the standard library would imply a significant performance impact.